# Spring roo permissionEvaluator throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-roo

I have a Spring Roo project and I'm trying to use the permissionEvaluator command to secure the application.
Command:

```
permissionEvaluator --package com.company.app.controllers
```

The following error is thrown,

```
NullPointerException at org.springframework.roo.addon.security.PermissionEvaluatorMetadataProvider.getMetadata(PermissionEvaluatorMetadataProvider.java:150)
```

I'm using the Roo Shell in STS installed on Eclipse Luna SR2. 
Is there some extra addon I need to add to my pom.xml for this to work? 
Thank you.

Full error,

```
Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT/applicationContext-security-permissionEvaluator.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/company/app/web/ApplicationPermissionEvaluator.java
Undo create SRC_MAIN_JAVA/com/company/app/web/ApplicationPermissionEvaluator.java
Undo create SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT/applicationContext-security-permissionEvaluator.xml
NullPointerException at org.springframework.roo.addon.security.PermissionEvaluatorMetadataProvider.getMetadata(PermissionEvaluatorMetadataProvider.java:150)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just solved https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3609 and it will be available on Spring Roo 2.0 version.

Regards,

Comment: Is there any way I could use the command before the release of version 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug. Would you create a ticket on [Spring Roo JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO)? Include Spring Roo version and, if it's possible, attach a project backup or a `.roo` script to reproduce it.

Thank you!